# Unable to install pip

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I tried installing pip in the following different ways and didn't have any success, any guidance how can I install pip ?

```
username@machine ~]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install pip
[sudo] password for username: 
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

[username@machine ~]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 pip
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')

[username@machine ~]$ python -m pip
/usr/local/bin/python: No module named pip
[username@machine ~]$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo: apt-get: command not found

[username@machine ~]$ sudo yum install python-pip
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Machine configuration:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: OracleServer
Description:    Oracle Linux Server release 6.6
Release:    6.6
Codename:   n/a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following for python2.7:

> sudo apt install python-pip

And if you alternatively want to install on python3:

> sudo apt install python3-pip

Comment: also I tried as `sudo easy_install-2.7 pip` which gives error `sudo: easy_install-2.7: command not found` even though easy_install-2.7 is present

Comment: For your distribution, oracle linux 6, you have to install EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) first. Use this article (https://blogs.oracle.com/wim/using-epel-repos-with-oracle-linux) and scroll to "Original Content" for more information. After installing EPEL, you should be able to run: 

`sudo yum install python-pip` (As you tried earlier, but didn't have EPEL)

Comment: great help..that helped

Comment: Remember to verify my answer so people in the future know it works. Thanks.

Comment: this however did not install pip for python 2.7 ?how do force install pip for python 2.7 on my machine?I get the error `[]$ which pip
/usr/bin/pip
[]$ python2.7 -m /usr/bin/pip install numpy
/usr/local/bin/python2.7: No module named /usr/bin/pip`

Comment: First, try to update `sudo yum -y update`. Then do `sudo yum -y install python-pip`. You can also use curl. `curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"`  and then `python get-pip.py`. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I did `sudo yum -y update` and then`sudo yum -y install python-pip`  still says `Package python-pip-7.1.0-1.el6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Comment: Try uninstalling pip and reinstalling without updating. Then, try updating. `sudo pip uninstall pip` to uninstall. And `pip install --upgrade pip` to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked, I had to do the following for OL7, as per the [official docs](https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-python.html#Python2Support):

```
yum install -y oracle-epel-release-el7 oracle-release-el7
```